# `WindowListener` acting up, perpetual firing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog, windowlistener

I have an application with an abstract class that extends `JDialog`. The class as an `abstract void onClose()`, and, in the class's constructor, the following code is added:

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        onClose();
    }
}
```

The event is fired when expected, but then a strange thing happens. When a concrete extension of this class has code to create a new `JDialog` in the `onClose()` method, and this `JDialog`'s `defaultCloseOperation` is `JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE`, the event is fired continuously, until I force quit the operation.

I have isolated the code to the following SSCCE:

```
// package removed
// imports removed
public class SSCCE extends JDialog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SSCCE s = new SSCCE();
        s.pack();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }
    public SSCCE() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
        JButton btn = new JButton("click me");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out
                        .println("SSCCE.SSCCE().new WindowAdapter() {...}.windowClosed()");
                onClose();
            }
        });
        add(btn);
    }

    public void onClose() {
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Upon clicking the "click me" button, the blank `JDialog` appears and `SSCCE.SSCCE().new WindowAdapter() {...}.windowClosed()` appears in the console window. When I close the blank dialog, it reappears again and the text appears again.

Another really interesting thing is that when I change the initialization line from

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
```

to

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void addWindowListener(WindowListener l) {
            super.addWindowListener(l);
            System.out
                    .println("SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()");
        }
    };
```

I get the following output in the console:

When clicking the "click me" button:

```
SSCCE.SSCCE().new WindowAdapter() {...}.windowClosed()
SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()
SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()
```

At the first closing of the dialog:

```
SSCCE.SSCCE().new WindowAdapter() {...}.windowClosed()
SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()
SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()
SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()
SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()
```

At the second closing of the dialog:

```
SSCCE.SSCCE().new WindowAdapter() {...}.windowClosed()
SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()
SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()
SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()
SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()
SSCCE.onClose().new JDialog() {...}.addWindowListener()
```

Each time I close the dialog, `addWindowListener(WindowListener l)` is called an *additional* time, even though it I am not intentionally calling it.

I don't really want *any* `WindowListener`s to be registered on the dialog, but I think that simply overriding the `addWindowListener(...)` method and not calling `super.addWindowListener(...)` would be too sloppy.

I'm running Java 1.6.0_31 on Mac OS X 10.6.8, using Eclipse Indigo (with WindowBuilder, if it matters).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [Java Dialog tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html),

> Every dialog is dependent on a Frame component. When that Frame is destroyed, so are its dependent Dialogs.

When you use the [JDialog constructor without any arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28%29), it

> Creates a modeless dialog without a title and without a specified Frame owner. A shared, hidden frame will be set as the owner of the dialog.

That shared hidden frame is `SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame`, and on initialization it registers a `WindowListener` to all owned windows.

When you close your dialog, the `SharedOwnerFrame`'s `windowClosed` method is called, which checks for all windows it owns (at this point is the original SSCCE dialog and the new one), it finds none are visible, and so it disposes itself. This has the impact of disposing all of the dialogs it owns, which posts a window close event to each. This calls `windowClosed` in your listener, opening a new dialog. And round we go again :-). Regarding your last comments, you get additional log lines each time because you get one per dialog the `SharedOwnerFrame` owns.

If you make the SSCCE dialog **own** the new dialog (by passing `this` into its constructor) then you don't end up with shared ownership and it works fine:

```
 public void onClose() {
     JDialog dialog = new JDialog(this);
     dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
     dialog.setVisible(true);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SSCCE extends JDialog {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SSCCE s = new SSCCE();
        s.pack();
        s.setVisible(true);
    }

    private WindowAdapter wa = new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            System.out
                    .println("SSCCE.SSCCE().new WindowAdapter() {...}.windowClosed()");
            onClose();
        } 
    };

    public SSCCE() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));
        JButton btn = new JButton("click me");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
        addWindowListener(
        wa);
        add(btn);
    }

    public void onClose() {
        removeWindowListener(wa);
        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: I see what you've done, and I see why it works, but I'm really wondering why the listener (`wa`) is getting added to `dialog` in the first place. Could you explain to me why?

Comment: I wish I had a good answer for you. I think it may have to do with the fact that your class extends JDialog.

Comment: user1291492 `with the fact that your class extends JDialog` +++++ 1k, exactly

Comment: @mKorbel: Can you elaborate? How does this contribute to the error?

Comment: +!.  Note that the pre/code type of tags used when posting that code do not produce context formatting.  For best code formatting, select the code and click the `{}` button above the message posting/editing form. :)

Comment: @WChargin my answer answers you question of 'why?', and offers (IMHO) a simpler solution.