# JDialog windowClosed firing indefinitely

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm having an issue where closing a JDialog causes the windowClosed event to fire indefinitely, until I force-close the application.  Whenever the dialog is disposed (via the window's X button, or the custom JButton), the dialog will close and the windowClosed event will fire ceaselessly.  Here is a short, complete class that demonstrates the behavior:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DialogEx extends JOptionPane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JOptionPane pane;
        final JDialog dialog;
        JButton exitButton = new JButton("Exit");

        pane = new JOptionPane(exitButton, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        pane.setComponentOrientation((getRootFrame()).getComponentOrientation());
        pane.setMessageType(PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        pane.setOptions(new Object[] {});
        dialog = pane.createDialog(null, "Dialog");
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent wE) {
                System.out.println("windowClosing fired");
                dialog.dispose();
            }
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent wE) {
                System.out.println("windowClosed fired");
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });

        exitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dialog.dispose();
            }
        });

        dialog.pack();
        dialog.validate();
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

What's going on here?
I found this similar problem [`WindowListener` acting up, perpetual firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10237047/windowlistener-acting-up-perpetual-firing). The symptom is the same, but I'm not quite sure the cause is the same, and the answer provided doesn't apply to my problem.

Comment: Works fine for me using JDK8 on Windows 7. The only thing I can suggest is to get rid of the `dialog.dispose()` in the `windowClosed()` method. You only need the `dialog.dispose()` in the `windowClosing()`.

Comment: You're absolutely right, removing `dialog.dispose()` from `windowClosed()` does indeed resolve the problem.  It seems that the `windowClosed()` method gets fired once the window has actually been disposed, so it makes no sense to dispose it again.  Thanks.